# Multi google codes in one page

Tags: google-analytics

We have this code on the website.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-40584814-1', 'webistename.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

How can I add another account to it? Can I add something like this?

Can I add something like this?

```
 <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-40584814-1', 'webistename.com');
      **ga('create', 'UA-472147-1', 'webistename.com');**
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

I tried that and I can't see the stats on the new account. How can I achieve this? I know I could invite someone via an email but I want to add a completely new account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Universal Analytics (not the original Async version), you have to pass it within the create statement via the options object:

```js
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {
  'name': 'foo'
});

// later on...
ga('send', 'pageview');     // sends to account XXXXXX-X
ga('foo.send', 'pageview'); // sends to account XXXXXX-Y
```

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this and it's working for the 2nd account. Will it work for the first and initial account too :)?

Comment: The first account doesn't require a name, no. In the code example above you'll see the first one (-X) doesn't require a name, but all further accounts will.

Answer (score -1):

Asynchronous tracking code my friend ;)

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?hl=pl#MultipleCommands

Comment: So this how my code will look like? `<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  _gaq.push(
  ['_setAccount', 'UA-40584814-1'],
  ['_trackPageview'],
  ['b._setAccount', 'UA-472147-1'],
  ['b._trackPageview']
);

</script>

Thanks a lot.`

Comment: Check if your account is Universal or Classic. From your question it seems your account is Universal already (the new version). In this case just ignore this answer.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/